# replace values of a dictionary with elements from a list in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list : `operation = [5,6]` and a dictionary `dic = {0: None, 1: None}`

And I want to replace each values of dic with the values of operation.

I tried this but it don't seem to run.

```
operation = [5,6]

for i in oper and val, key in dic.items():
        dic_op[key] = operation[i]
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Try using `zip` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) method will do the job

```
operation = [5, 6]
dic = {0: None, 1: None}

for key, op in zip(dic, operation):
  dic[key] = op

print(dic)   # {0: 5, 1: 6}
```

The above solution assumes that `dic` is ordered in order that element position in `operation` is align to the keys in the `dic`.

Answer (score 2):

Other option, maybe:

```
operation = [5,6]
dic = {0: None, 1: None}

for idx, val in enumerate(operation):
  dic[idx] = val

dic #=> {0: 5, 1: 6}
```

Details for using index here: [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in Python 3.7+, you could just do:

```
operation = [5,6]
dic = {0: None, 1: None}

print(dict(zip(dic, operation)))
# {0: 5, 1: 6}
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume `dic` keys are ordered appropriately?

Comment: @jpp, yes it does. In Python 3.7+, I believe they are inherently ordered.

Comment: Yup, the problem is we shouldn't assume OP is defining the dictionary manually in `operation` order (they may or may not be). At the least it should be noted.